# How to implement SLEEP mode on a PIC12F675 microcontroller?

Tags: c, embedded, pic

I am working on a project where I need to conserve power (I am using two AA batteries) by putting a PIC12F675 microcontroller into low-energy consumption mode. Specifically, I want to set up the microcontroller to wake up every five hours, take a measurement, and then go back to sleep to conserve energy. Can anyone provide guidance on how to achieve this?

I am looking for advice on how to put the PIC12F675 into low-energy consumption mode, as well as how to set up a timer or interrupt to wake up the microcontroller every five hours. Any code examples or suggested approaches would be greatly appreciated.

I have a project that can perform the required tasks, but I want to reduce power consumption since it is a battery-powered system. To achieve this, I plan to implement sleep mode and watchdog timer. However, I am new to programming microcontrollers and have not been able to find any guidance on the internet. I would appreciate any advice on how to use sleep mode and watchdog timer for power saving purposes, or any recommended resources for beginners in microcontroller programming.

EDIT:
I have already implemented the SLEEP method with the following code:

```
#pragma config FOSC = INTRCIO   // Oscillator Selection bits (INTOSC oscillator: I/O function on GP4/OSC2/CLKOUT pin, I/O function on GP5/OSC1/CLKIN)
#pragma config WDTE = ON        // Watchdog Timer Enable bit (WDT disabled)
#pragma config PWRTE = OFF      // Power-Up Timer Enable bit (PWRT disabled)
#pragma config MCLRE = OFF      // GP3/MCLR pin function select (GP3/MCLR pin function is digital I/O, MCLR internally tied to VDD)
#pragma config BOREN = OFF      // Brown-out Detect Enable bit (BOD disabled)
#pragma config CP = OFF         // Code Protection bit (Program Memory code protection is disabled)
#pragma config CPD = OFF        // Data Code Protection bit (Data memory code protection is disabled)

// X8 compiler header include
#include <xc.h>
#define _XTAL_FREQ 4000000

void main(void) {
    // Clear the WDT
    CLRWDT();
    
    // Enable interrupts
    INTCONbits.GIE = 1;
    INTCONbits.PEIE = 1;
    
    // Setup GPIO pin
    TRISIO0 = 0;
    
    while(1) {
        SLEEP();
        // Main program loop
        GPIO0 = 1;
        __delay_ms(1000);
        GPIO0 = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i<7826; i++){
            SLEEP();
        }
        // Clear the WDT periodically
        CLRWDT();
    }
}
```

Is there any way to modify this code to further improve battery life?

Comment: According to section 9.6.1 of the [datasheet](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/aemDocuments/documents/MCU08/ProductDocuments/DataSheets/41190G.pdf) for the PIC12F675, the longest period the watchdog timer can be set to is 2.3 seconds. So it's going to be a bit clunky. A better solution would be to use a microcontroller with a real-time clock.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour] to learn how this site works, and read "[ask]". This is not a forum. --  If you are _that_ new, it is going to be a steep and high learning curve, and commonly there is no way around reading, experimenting, failing, and repeat. Divide your target project into very small easier problems and tackle each of them separately.

Comment: Dear @pmacfarlane , thank you for your suggestion. While I understand that the WDT can be set to just 2.3 seconds, I am curious if it is possible to achieve a longer interval by enclosing it in a while or for loop. Additionally, I am struggling with the implementation of the WDT even for the 2.3-second interval. Would it be possible for you to provide me with a code example of its basic usage so that I can try it out on my own? I would greatly appreciate your help.

Comment: @Samuel Unfortunately I don't have any experience with these microcontrollers at all. I was just interested so looked at the datasheet.

Comment: Do you have some event happening at 5 hours that could be used to trigger wakeup via GPIO?

Comment: @pmacfarlane You can work with that easily, every 2.3s a counter is decremented and if it doesn't hit 0, the controller goes to sleep again. a 16bit counter is enough for 5h. When the counter hits 0, the measurement is taken, the counter is set to 7826, and the controller goes back to sleep. The current is a bit higher with a wakeup every 2.3s, but still low. And Timer1 can be programmed to a 16s interval and used as wakeup.

Comment: What is your clock source? And what battery do you have and how long do you need to run it (how much effort is justified to improve battery life)?

Comment: @12431234123412341234123 I am using internal clock 4MHz. I would be glad if it could last at least few months on two or three AA batteries.

Comment: I can't read that code, if the `{` and `}` would be aligned it would be much easier to read. The `CLRWDT()` is not needed, since the WDT is 0 after the WDT wakes the µC up. Why do you `SLEEP()` at the start of the `main` loop? Setting unused GPIOs as output XOR (not both) enable pullups is also advices, don't let GPIOs float. How much current does the µC draw (without LED)? Why do you use a (signed) `int` for the `for` loop? Durring the 1s busy loop, the µC will draw "a lot" of power (relatively, because it takes so long), how long will the real measurement take? Why enable the interrupts?

Comment: @12431234123412341234123 Thank you for addressing all the points in your comment. As I am new to microcontrollers, I may not have a clear understanding of all the functionalities. Is it possible to change the length of SLEEP somehow? When I run the code above it takes about 2s to wake up from the sleep.

Comment: @Samuel This is near the expected 2.3s. Read the datasheet, in section 9.7.1 (Wakeup from SLEEP) you have a list of things that can wake you up from sleep. You currently use the WDT. As described in section 9.6.1 WDT PERIOD you can change the WDT prescaler with OPTION_REG (section 2.2.2.2), for a finer adjustment you need a software solution (as you do with the  7826). But keep in mind the WDT tolerances are very high (factor 2.5 between minimum and maximum, TABLE 12-4). How accurate should the timing be?

Comment: @12431234123412341234123 Thank you. I really don't need to have very accurate timing for my measurement (+-  few minutes is enough). Is there any limit how long can the measurement be when Iam using WDT? Because I want to take a measurement (few ms) and then (due to measurement result) turn on a relay for a few seconds (if it is needed). And the second question, is it possible to use external interrupt with WDT on ?

Comment: @Samuel You contradict yourself. Do you need a more accurate timing, to get down to a few minutes, or is the factor of 2.5 small enough (this means timing could vary between 2.5h and 6.25h, or other times with the same factor in between)? You have to reset the WDT every about 1.2s (or more. There is no problem in resetting WDT often), but you need power (battery) for µC and the relay while the relay is on. External interrupts work fine with WDT on.

Comment: @12431234123412341234123 My primary objective is to obtain a single measurement every 5 hours, with an acceptable deviation of approximately 1 hour. Another important task is to conserve the battery's energy if the GP5 reading indicates 0V, which would imply that the system controlled by the microcontroller has an empty tank. Continue in the next comment =>

Comment: To achieve this, I plan to power down all the pins and put the microcontroller to sleep mode until someone refills the tank and the voltage on GP5 returns to 5V. Therefore, to trigger an external interrupt caused by a change from 0V to 5V on GP5, I only need to set INTCONbits.GPIE to 1. After the interrupt wakes the microcontroller from sleep mode, I can reset the flag bit by setting INTCONbits.GPIF = 0. Is my understanding of the process correct?

Comment: Read the datasheet, the section about GPIO (3) and about interrupts (9.4), try it, if the interrupt doesn't work, try to fix it, if it still doesn't work, ask a new question. You wake up ever 2.3s because the WDT isn't longer, you could poll it then and don't use a interrupt (maybe simpler to do). After you have a solution, measure the current in the different modes to estimate battery lifetime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start simple:
Use a Testboard where you can control a LED with a GPIO. Make sure you can control the LED with your code, with something like a loop that just toggles the LED with a short pause (to check if your code runs, LED pin is correct, Pin is set as output, ...). After you are sure you can control the LED, you can set up the WDT

After you set up the WDT and go to sleep in the main loop, toggle the LED, go to sleep again. The WDT should be work just fine once setup, as long as you return to sleep fast enough.

```
#include <xc.h>

void main(void)
{
  //Put to code to setup GPIOs here
  //Put to code to setup WDT here
  while(1)
  {
    SLEEP();
    //Put code to toggle LED here
  }
}
```

After you have that, you put the `SLEEP()` macro / instruction in a for loop with a counter of `7826` (well, a bit lower till you are sure everything else works as testing with such a long delay is annoying).
Please keep in mind that the WDT timer source is far from precise, it has a huge tolerance. That also means your 5h will be of. You could use a RTC if you need higher precision, but then you don't need the WDT but can use a alarm function of the RTC.

Comment: Thank you for your helpful answer. I've successfully implemented the LED blinking as I had intended. I was wondering if you could review my code to confirm that everything is set up correctly and suggest any improvements that could potentially save battery life.